# Correct use of Repository / Service Classes

Tags: c#, design-patterns, service, domain-driven-design, repository

Im working on a fairly light weight client application (desktop app in .Net as connect to other applications maybe needed in the future) for tracking of RMAs within a business for the engineers, engineers will view and update the status in the application, customers will create/view RMAs on the website.

I want to know if my intended use of service and repository classes are correct. A web service provides the data in JSON format from which I can construct an `RMA`object. This web service is accessed by `http://myRMA.com/repairs/2234/RMA.JSON`

Would the code to get the RMA sit within `RMARepository` class with a method like `GetRMA(int RMAId)`, and should the `RMARepository` follow the singleton design pattern?

Whereas if the RMA is updated, i.e. Item is inspecting and pending a quote acceptance, is this completed in a service class, which calls a RMARepository to submit an update. Would the `IsExists(int RMAId)` be in this service class or be in the repository?

I am familiar with Presentation - Application (Logic) - Data Access - Data (Database) artitecture, and also with MVP. But i do wonder where the `Service` classes fit in.

Comment: Effectively I know what I need to achieve, and even how to achieve it but need to know where to draw the line in placing functionality in this style of architecture.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The repository classes are only used to access and store information in the database. They should have no other logic.

Services are used to fetch information from a data source (most likely a repository), process the information and return the result to the caller.

A service class can use multiple repositories to achieve the wanted result. In this layer you can also have a event system which can allow one service to take actions when another service have generated an event.

An example would be that the the UserService calls the FeedService to create a new RSS feed item for each newly created user.

The Repository layer can be represented by a ORM such as nhibernate.

Comment: Would it be a fair comment that the controller/presenter in the presentation layer that wanted to display RMA details would call a service class which forwards the call onto 1 or more repositories to create the desired object. I.e. The view/controller/model never touch the repository classes.

Comment: Yes. That's the proper way to do it. It makes it easy to extend applications and to test them.

Comment: @jguffin, Cheers, ill work that into my design. Do you happen to know any godo reading material for what defines a service, i.e. how much content I should put into them.

Comment: Nope. I usually have authorization (CAS), BO validation (ShureValidation/DataAnnotations) and logging (nLog) in my services. And of course logic to build/handle business objects. Keep in mind that having a `Save(myBusinessObject)` method in a service can make it hard to extend the application later on. It's better to have methods like `IncreateTax`, `AttachToGroup` etc. A `Save` method is a bit too general (in most cases)

Comment: @jgauffin What if I have a service that does a lot of work that needs to be split into multiple files? Where do I keep these files? Let's say I have project `MySolution.Services`. Should I create new project for the extra files and put `MyService.cs` in `MySolution.Services` or just add a new folder in `MySolution.Services`?

Comment: That's a generic question. What kind of work? Is multiple different entities involved? Typically I want to break things down so that each type of entity (business object) have it's own service.